# Fill ViewModel Property Based on website culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, globalization

First of all excuse me for my language.
I have an MVC web application that support many languages,
for example i've got a group table with the following schema

```
Id int
EnglishName varchar
FrenshName varchar
```

admin user will be able to fill this table

when selecting records from that table to display it on a particular page
EnglishName should appear if the user is using the application in English culture, FrenshName should appear if the user is using the application in Frensh culture...
i've never done this before

i don't know from where should i start searching, and i would be grateful if someone provide me with a solution or links where i could find one,

**NOTE**: i can't use resources because its dynamic inserted data.

Comment: thank you in advance, am searching too but could not find anything yet

Comment: This question is a little too broad, but you can take a look at [Request.UserLanguages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.userlanguages(v=vs.110).aspx), which you can use in the controller to get the user's language preferences, then you can query your database based on that.